# Use the categorical values of columns to delete the idex in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, delete-row

I made a simple data as follow:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                 a=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                 b=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0))
```

`id` stands for specific id number of a person. What I want to do now is delete the whole `id` if `a`equals 1. Aso, I want to delete the whole `id` if `b` equals 1.
In this example, the desired output should be like this:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(2,2,2),
                 a=c(0,0,0),
                 b=c(0,0,0))
```

In my actual data, there are hundreds of `id`,so I want to know method to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Base R`,

```
data[!(data$id %in% unique(data[(data$a == 1) |  (data$b == 1),"id"])),]
```

gives,

```
#       id a b
#     4  2 0 0
#     5  2 0 0
#     6  2 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, with `if_all`:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(if_all(a:b, ~ all(.x != 1)))

#      id     a     b
# 1     2     0     0
# 2     2     0     0
# 3     2     0     0
```